# JSON values from objects inside an Array

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-10

So i have this json column in my postgres (v.10) database.

It can look like this:

```
[{"_destroy": false, "gruppe_id": "verwalter"}, {"_destroy": "", "gruppe_id": "budget_nur_anzeigen"}]
```

I just want to get values from the gruppe_id elements concatenated in a new column like this:

```
Gruppe_ID
verwalter, budget_nur_anzeigen
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/71ab9/1)

Comment: The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: Unrelated, but: [don't use `char`](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29)  and JSON data should be stored in a `jsonb` column

Comment: Do you really need a comma separated result? It would be quite easy to get it as a JSON array, using `jsonb_path_query_array(context_data::jsonb, '$[*].gruppe_id')`

Comment: Yes i know, i don't want more get more rows like in jsonb_array_elements. In my DB it's not a json field it's a text field

Comment: json_path_query is not in postgres 10 as far as i know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unnest the array, then aggregate back:

```
select m.id, 
       (select string_agg(c.item ->> 'gruppe_id', ',')
        from jsonb_array_elements(m.context_data::jsonb) as c(item)) as gruppe_id
from mutations m;
```